# The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction. Rebus

Tags: c#, sql-server, rebus

I am facing an issue while handling the message using Rebus. Below is the complete stack trace I can see but not able to figure out what is the actual issue.

I am also awaiting my bus calls like below but still getting the quoted issue below.

1. Bus.SendLocal(message).Wait()
2. Bus.Publish(message).Wait()
3. Bus.Send(message).Wait()

> Rebus.Retry.ErrorTracking.InMemErrorTracker                                                       Unhandled exception 1 while handling message with ID "b1823872-95b7-419c-a543-f63734705068" System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Commit()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit()     at Rebus.SqlServer.DbConnectionWrapper.d__8.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at Rebus.SqlServer.Transport.SqlServerTransport.<>c__DisplayClass38_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at Rebus.Transport.TransactionContext.d__24.MoveNext() in C:\projects-rebus\Rebus\Rebus\Transport\TransactionContext.cs:line 131  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at Rebus.Transport.TransactionContext.d__17.MoveNext() in C:\projects-rebus\Rebus\Rebus\Transport\TransactionContext.cs:line 58  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at Rebus.Retry.Simple.SimpleRetryStrategyStep.d__10.MoveNext() in C:\projects-rebus\Rebus\Rebus\Retry\Simple\SimpleRetryStrategyStep.cs:line 122  ClientConnectionId:23e19a70-b9f5-4137-858d-67a541193177  Error Number:3981,State:1,Class:16

I am using the following version:

1. Rebus 5.3.1.0
2. Rebus.SqlServer 5.1.0.0

It would be great if someone provides a heads-up so that I can pin out the issue. Thanks.

So more details are below.

Working on an object type let's say "CommandMessage" which we receive in rebus handler like below. When the whole process successfully completes I am sending the further the message into the rebus queue by adding the post-commit action on unitOfWork, here it fails sometimes. That is if there are let's say 3 messages in the queue which get picked up by handlers, all these messages when sent to the bus by using **Bus.Send(message).Wait()** sometimes 1-2 messages fail with the error **"System.AggregateException: 5 unhandled exceptions ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction."**

This is the rebus configuration being used currently.

```
<SqlServerTransportConfig ConnectionName="RebusConnection" InputQueue="InputQ" ErrorQueue="ErroQ" NumberOfWorkerThreads="10" MaxParallelism="10" MaxRetries="5" UseDeadLetterQueue="True" UseJournalQueue="False" />
```

We never faced this kind of issue in any of our environments before, until now.

```
public Task Handle(CommandMessage message)
{
 UnitOfWorkOrchestrator.Execute(
        TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
        IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
        unitOfWork =>
        {
          try
          {
            ....do work...
            SubmitMessage(message, unitOfWork) //Passing parameters and unitOfWork
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            .....
          }
          finally
          {
            .....
          }
        });
      return Task.Delay(0);
    }
}

SomeObj SubmitMessage(message, unitOfWork) 
{
    ....performing some checks...
    ....do work....
    
    unitOfWork.AddPostCommitAction(() =>
        {
            switch (action)
            {
              case Publish:
                //Some logging
                Bus.Publish(message).Wait();
                break;
              case MessageDispositionAction.Send:
                //Some logging
                Bus.Send(message).Wait();       //Facing issue here
                break;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: See following : https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.SqlServer/issues/7?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng I had already visited the link before and it is talking about awaiting on the bus calls which I am already doing.

Comment: Adding `.Wait()` is not the same as awaiting, using the `await` keyword, try that first.

Comment: @T. Van Schagen, I know wait is synchronous like Thread.Sleep blocking the thread and await is asynchronous but the issue I am getting is of pending requests on transaction, don't you think when it is already synchronous then why I would get this issue at first place?

Comment: @SurajSharma I have to agree with the other two comments: The only way I know of that this type of error message can be had, is by missing an `await` somewhere. Also, did you you know Rebus has a synchronous bus? The `ISyncBus` retrieved from `bus.Advanced.SyncBus` has synchronous versions of all methods of `IBus` 

Comment: @mookid8000, I followed this link as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140393/rebus-send-message-in-queue-and-receive-in-another-application?answertab=votes#tab-top

and in the above link, you mentioned using either await or Wait. So I used Wait and I've checked multiple times if await or wait is missing anywhere but didn't find any, do you happen to know if a version is somehow playing that nasty part as I am using 5.3.1.0?

Comment: To my knowledge, Rebus.SqlServer has never had an issue that would cause the exception you're seeing. Are you, by any chance, doing something like `await Task.WhenAll(messages.Select(async msg => await bus.Send(msg)))` anywhere?

Comment: No, not using Task.WhenAll anywhere.

Comment: Could you maybe update the question with some more code? E.g. show exactly how you're sending, and where you're doing it?

Comment: @mookid8000, added more details.

Comment: When you `AddPostCommitAction` on your unit of work, when will it be executed? I think the error is that the post commit action is executed too late somehow, after Rebus' unit of work has actually finished.

Comment: it executes immediately after the SubmitMessage() call ends. Also, I've checked the code is not failing anywhere and it goes to post-commit action.

try
{
  ....do work...
  SubmitMessage(message, unitOfWork) //Passing parameters and unitOfWork
}

Comment: I'd like to see how `UnitOfWorkOrchestrator`, because I think the key to understanding this error lies in there. Can you update the question with that?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am still pretty sure that the implementation of `UnitOfWorkOrchestrator` can somehow explain how this exception can occur.

Comment: @mookid8000, I had to dig down deep into all the internal libraries we were using which took time, and ultimately I found out that internally we were using another bus to write some audit entries into the database which was not getting awaited. So the bus call on top of the code did not know that there was another nested bus and when the top-level bus tried to commit its transaction it saw that internally another transaction is still open. Hence, the error. I've fixed that library so all is good now, thanks a lot for the helpful insights.